# Preconfigured Intel Raid Array Mount in Ubuntu

Tags: mount, raid

I would like to mount a preconfigured Raid Array on my new Ubuntu Installation. Found relevant information to find it using sudu command in terminal. However, location of Raid is spanned across 3 drives.( three Locations.) How would I mount it( not sure but I  believer it RAID 05{??}. I have a lot of data on raid, please do not tell me to format :)  . Is there a GUI ????? the Raid is itel, X99 Motherboard. Cheers and Happy Holidays.

Comment: Is this Ubuntu **server**?

Comment: heynnema, it is for a fresh installation of Ubuntu Studio 18.10 “Cosmic Cuttlefish”. Thanx. :)

Comment: My understanding is that server works with RAID, desktop (and I supposed Studio) don't. Check help.ubuntu.com for more info on RAID on non-server installations.

Comment: Thank you for your response hey heynnema. Kinda hoping for something different, but that's not your fault. I guess I need to install Ubuntu server(???? :( !!!   )